# Where to look in order to edit text on PHP website?

Tags: php

A friend of mine asked me to help him edit and add content to his PHP website.  It was originally created by a professional company which has now became his opponent.

I thought it would be easy to edit some texts and adding content based on an original template. I downloaded all the files from a server, but couldn't find any files that contained the text I wanted to edit.

1. How could I use the text search keyword in all those files: PHP & JS without opening them one by one to find it as it seems to having too many files related with one simple website?
2. What is the best way to check whether or not I am in need of the original files in order to finish this project?

Comment: How's the URL of the page you need to edit? Do you need to change code or just content? is it a framework or a CMS? not clear so far..

Comment: you may be trying to edit a dymanic page. try if there is an admin panel.

Comment: making the question more detailed may help. you should provide the url of the page that u r tryin to edit

Comment: @mithunsatheesh: Yes there is an admin folder. Does it mean that the content is editable/addable?

Comment: @modular: dude you type in yoursitename/admin in address bar and login to the panel with your username, pwd then make changes.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound like a programming question.

Searching the files largely depends on what operating system you're using and what tools you have available.  There are many tools such as grep/awk on Unix/Linux systems, and file search tools on Windows and Mac.

The text you want to edit may be stored in a database.  Often, PHP sites are part of a LAMP (Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP) stack with MySQL being the database layer.  If this is the case, you would need to get the information from the database, too.

Answer (score 0):

This definitely not a programming question as calvinf said .... and there are tools you can use to search keywords in all the files of your project...
Try Zend Studio and after making a project in it search for your keywords in All Files option...
Another possibility you would not be able to find files is because the text might be saved in the db and extracted at the runtime...
so in my opinion if later is the case you would have to have a look at the templates stored in your db...
But i won't mind to have a go at Zend if i were you, anyways.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful advice. Unfortunately neither couldn't find any text keyword in all those files nor no sql (or any DB type) seems to be existing in the project. The developer said to provide with CMS for adding some contents in the future but I couldn't be able to login from the URL given.